# Is there a way to set state from a child component to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a parent screen View Trade with modal.I want to close this modal when the close button is pressed in AddTrade screen. The hardware back button is disabled but would it be possible to simulate the hardware button press?
I want to close the modal when submit is pressed but both are in different screen.

```
//View Trade
render() {
    const {
      navigation,
    } = this.props;
    return (      
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', borderWidth: 2}}>
          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            <TextInput placeholder="City" />
          </View>
          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Pokemon" />
          </View>
          <Icon
            name="search"
            type="font-awesome"
            iconStyle={{
              color: '#e6f2fd',
              backgroundColor: '#2096f3',
              padding: 10,
              marginVertical: '10%',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('search');
            }}
          />
        </View>
        {this._makeCards()}
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            console.log('add');
            // this.props.navigation.navigate('Add Trades')
            this.setState({isModalVisible:!this.state.isModalVisible})
          }}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            height: '10%',
            width: '20%',
            bottom: '8%',
            right: '3%',
          }}>
          <View>
            <Image source={require('../assets/images/float-add-icon.png')} />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal visible={this.state.isModalVisible} onRequestClose={()=>{this.setState({isModalVisible:!this.state.isModalVisible})}} style={{margin:0,flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <AddTrades navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

```
//AddTrade
return (
      <View>
        <View style={[styles.app, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}>
          <Picker
            style={styles.picker}
            selectedValue={this.state.WhatTheyGive}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              this.setState({WhatTheyGive: itemValue})
            }>
            {this.addPicker()}
          </Picker>
          <TextInput placeholder="Enter CP" style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Enter city" style={styles.textInput} />
          <Picker
            style={styles.picker}
            selectedValue={this.state.whatTheyWant}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              this.setState({whatTheyWant: itemValue})
            }>
            {this.addPicker()}
          </Picker>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            // I want to hide modal when this is pressed.
            <Button title="Submit" onPress={this._onSubmit} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: please explain more about your problem, add screenshot and code if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a method to change the isModalVisible value. then pass the method to your `<AddTrade callback={method} />` .

Then in the child component call this callback method when Button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Make parent component dependent on the state. i.e

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  childValue: false
} }

<View style={{backgroundColor:this.state.childValue?"red":"green"}}> //Parent View
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({childValue:true)}> //ChildrenView 
<Text>Click Me</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize `renderProps` approach on this one.

Your `Modal` component somewhere in `render` method renders `children` prop.
Instead of just rendering `children` prop, call it as a function `children(...)` and pass in any arguments you want (in your case, pass in `Modal`'s `onRequestClose` function).

```
// somethere in the render method:
   {children(props.onRequestClose)}
```

Afterwards, instead of rendering `<AddTrades />` as is, pass in an expression that is a function containing your `AddTrades` instance (with your `onRequestClose` function as an argument!). Pass that function to your `AddTrades` easily (and to any other modal children).

```
<Modal visible={this.state.isModalVisible} onRequestClose={()=>{this.setState({isModalVisible:!this.state.isModalVisible})}}>
    {(onRequestClose) => <AddTrades onRequestClose={onRequestClose} />}
</Modal>
```

In the end, simply call `props.onRequestClose` in `AddTrades` component.